# Is it possible to have one layout showing differently for different button clicks?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

Hello I am building a tipping app where the user tips based on % value or $ money

I have a buttons set up for % value that activates a layout which asks user to enter the tip % , Now my Question is can i use the same layout when the userclicks $button and instead of asking user to input tip %value, I ask him $amount.

I know it is possible to do it as two separate activities but I was wondering the possibilities of using one layout showing differently based on button click.

Comment: Assuming that same layout means a single `.xml` file, yes you  can.

Comment: Yes I mean same .xml but it displaying differently for different button click.

Comment: You mean like the view doesn't show up until _after_ you click the button?

Comment: I mean my single .xml file shows up differently for different button click, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you asked. 
Simply, change the text in the textfield you have for your text entry to ask the use to enter whatever value they like and then set a boolean flag in your code to indicate that the value entered is a special value an not the "input tip %value".

Another solution would be to add another EditText field and set it's visibility to GONE and when you need to use it, set the old (%tip) EditText field to GONE and the new ($amount) EditText to VISIBLE so that you don't need to keep track of updating a variable to indicate what text has been entered into shared EditText.